# Facing issue while using CORS in a sample project

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code for sending in request to a website for ping.
I don't want to use jsonp (it works fine with that). 
I was trying to implement cors but still getting the issue of header "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."
I kind of tried all the links online but non of them worked so far.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://example.com//payme/',
    type: 'post',

    crossDomain: true,
    strictSSL: false,
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "test": false,
        "language": "en",
        "command": "PING",
        "merchant": {
            "apiLogin": "test",
            "apiKey": "test"
        }
    }),

    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET, POST, PUT'
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.info(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: If it "works fine with JSONP" then that is your only choice; the site doesn't allow AJAX requests from other domains.

Comment: That is where CORS comes in Genius & that is what I asked for.

Comment: CORS is something that has to be done by the website you're trying to access. If that site doesn't respond with CORS headers, and you cannot force them to change that, then you cannot use AJAX.

Comment: Some websites block request from file:// and localhost:// you can deploy in a public server and check if it is working, nothing wrong with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CORS headers HAVE to be supplied by the server.  They are NOT something you can add in your request from the client.

The server adds the CORS headers to the response and that gives the browser permission to allow the cross-origin request.  If the CORS headers are not present, the browser will disallow the request.  You can't fix this from the client.  CORS has to be specifically supported on the server.